# Writing a Grails Script that references another Script

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using the Grails release plugin, see: http://grails.org/plugin/release, version 2.2.0 to publish plugin to a local repo.

I want to write my own Grails script which invokes: `publish-plugin` and then does a little bit extra.

I try:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_ReleasePlugins")

target(main: "This script packages the plugin and deletes any directories that are not needed and created by Grails") {
    println(">>packageTypes()")
    publishPlugin()
    //...

}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

I get:

```
| Error Error executing script PublishTypes: _ReleasePlugins (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _ReleasePlugins
    at java_lang_ClassLoader$loadClass.call(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see that there is a ReleasePlugins.groovy Gant script included with that plugin. Are you trying to use the old release-plugin script? (notice it's not plural)

Comment: @Joshua Moore I updated the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your issue is that you need to include the PublishPlugin Gant script instead of _ReleasePlugins. So try includeTargets << grailsScript("_PublishPlugin")

Comment: @Joshua Moore, that gives: | Error Error executing script PublishTypes: _PublishPlugin (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _PublishPlugin
 at java_lang_ClassLoader$loadClass.call(Unknown Source)
 at grails.util.BuildSettings$1.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:356)

Comment: Turns out the correct manner for including PublishPlugin is as follows: includeTargets << grailsScript("PublishPlugin_")

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thanks but for grails 2.2.1 I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for both includeTargets << grailsScript("PublishPlugin_")  and includeTargets << grailsScript("_PublishPlugin")

Comment: Hmm, okay. I don't have 2.2.1 but I tried that in 2.3.0 and it worked. You might have better luck asking on the Grails mailing list.